# Pass value from controller to controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm building my first iOS app to try and learn iOS coding. However, I need to pass a value `xAuthToken` from one controller to the other. I can't seem to get it working to. I init the value in the first controller `ViewController`, but then I need it in `SettingsController`. I keep getting errors and the one it throws now is: `Property 'ViewController' not found on object of type 'ViewController'`

What am I doing wrong?

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SettingsController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtUsername;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtPassword;

- (IBAction)sigininClicked:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender;
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) NSString *xAuthToken;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)sigininClicked:(id)sender {

    NSString *xAuthToken = @"0";

    self.viewController = [[SettingsController alloc] init];
    self.viewController.xAuthToken = xAuthToken;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login_success" sender:self];

}
```

**SettingsController.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SettingsController : UIViewController

@end
```

**SettingsController.m**

```
@interface SettingsController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *mySwitch;

@end

@implementation SettingsController

//THIS IS WHERE I NEED XAUTHTOKEN
```

Comment: You are attempting to assign a value to `self.viewController`, but you have not provided a property definition for this.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a segue that presents your `SettingsController`, pass the information it needs in `prepareForSegue`.  Don't create a new local `SettingsController`.

Comment: But I need to some posts in the SettingsView to a webserver. Is that possible without a dedicated `SettingsController`?

Comment: You'll have a SettingsController, assuming that's what your segue creates.  I just mean, don't create a different one in code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateviewcontrollerwithidentifier:@"your vc name"];
viewController.Xauthtoken = data;
// Do something else with this.
```

Or another way ( I don't know if it's good or bad, use it while your vc is already active ):
Use NSNotificationCenter and pass values between it.

Third way is create delegate for first Viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) NSString *xAuthToken;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)sigininClicked:(id)sender {
    xAuthToken = @"Your Value Here";
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login_success" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"login_success"]) {
       SettingsController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
       destViewController.xAuthToken = xAuthToken;
   }
}
```

And in your SettingsController.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SettingsController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *xAuthToken;

@end
```

SettingsController.m

```
@interface SettingsController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *mySwitch;

@end

@implementation SettingsController

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    NSLog("%@",xAuthToken);
}
```

Comment: I implemented your code, but now it crashes on this line: `_xAuthToken = [jsonData[@"token"] stringValue];`

Comment: Now I get `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setXAuthToken:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79837530`